# knex toString method conveting date timezone

Tags: knex.js

I have a table with the last_update value which is a timestamp with timezone on postgres 9.

If I execute the command everything works fine!

```js
knex('my_table')
        .where({id})
        .update({ last_update:  new Date()})
```

But if I store the toString of the command to execute later, which is basically what I need, I have a problem. The toString method is converting the dates before outputting the string... In other words, the command above is not the same as the one below:

```js
knex.raw(
         knex('my_table')
        .where({id})
        .update({ last_update:  new Date()}).toString()
)
```

I expect that executing the raw from a toString would be the same, but apparently not... If this is not a bug, how can I make the toString keep the object date and don't convert to any timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

https://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-toString

toString — .toString()
Returns an array of query strings filled out with the correct values based on bindings, etc. Useful for debugging, but should not be used to create queries for running them against DB.

Comment: Only useful for debugging... I still looking for a solution to store queries to execute them in batch in the future... A loop would not solve my problem.

Comment: .toSQL().toNative() should give parametrized sql + bindings for running with driver.